# PHP code looks fine but not updating

Tags: php, mysql, insert, content-management-system

I am currently creating a cms, all is fine apart from the add.php page.

My code for this page is this:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
      if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
             $title = $_POST['title'];
             $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
             $image = $_POST['Image URL'];
             $link = $_POST['Link'];
             $price = $_POST['Price'];

if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
             $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
}else{
 $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `apps`(`app_id`, `app_title`, `app_content`, `app_img`, `app_link`, `app_price`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6])');
$query->execute(array(
':title' => $title,
':content' => $content,
':image' => $image,
':link' => $link,
':price' => $price
));

     $query->execute();
}if($result){
        echo("<br>Input data is successful");
    } else{
        echo("<br>Input data failed");
    }

}
          ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

<br />


<h4>Add Article</h4>

<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
     <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
<?php } ?>


<form name = "myform" action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">


<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" placeholder="Content" name="content"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="Image URL" placeholder="Image URL" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="Link" placeholder="Link" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="Price" placeholder="Price" /><br /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Article" />

</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
}else{
       header('location: index.php');
}
error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>
```

My problem is. My code is not showing any errors in my error log and people tellme that it is fine. But it is not adding to the database. is there a way that I can break down each bit of code and find out what is going on?

or is there a way to display what the error may be? my error reporting is turned on with E_ALL | E_STRICT and still nothing.

please help

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your PDO query from

```
 $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `apps`(`app_id`, `app_title`, `app_content`, `app_img`, `app_link`, `app_price`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6])');
```

to be something like this

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `apps`(`app_title`, `app_content`, `app_img`, `app_link`, `app_price`) VALUES (:title,:content,:img,:link,:price)');
```

You should review how `PDO::prepare` method work with placeholders. Besides, if your `app_id` is an auto increment field. You need not include it in your insert query.

Comment: hi. my app Id is an auto increment, how do I add this?

Comment: Hi. So your `app_id` is your primary key or not? If you have your own mechanism to generate your `app_id`, just add the `app_id` field and its placeholder into the prepare statement as well as insert the generated id when using `execute` method. Otherwise, you should format this field as an auto increment field.

Comment: my app_id Is not a primary key. im not sure how to format this field as an auto increment field. please can you advise me how? thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me which information contains in the `app_id`. If it is not the primary key, you need not use auto increment in this field. You are free to use any type of data in `app_id`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this could work as the placeholders aren't using the correct notation and aren't named correctly.

Your query should look like:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `apps`(`app_id`, `app_title`, `app_content`, `app_img`, `app_link`, `app_price`) VALUES (:app_id, :app_title, :app_content, :app_img, :app_link, :app_price)');
$query->execute(array(
  ':app_id' => ???,
  ':app_title' => $title,
  ':app_content' => $content,
  ':app_img' => $image,
  ':app_link' => $link,
  ':app_price' => $price
));
```

Also you appear to be missing the `:app_id` parameter.

Comment: ok thanks for this. how do I get mysql to automatically insert the next number. for example I have 2 fields in the table at the moment one with the app_id as 1 the other woth the app_id as 2. what code do a repplace the ??? above with make it add an Id in numeric order?

Comment: If your `app_id` column is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then you can just omit that column on the `INSERT` and it will be filled in for you.